# Wordpress: restrict sign up as subscriber to selected countries

Tags: wordpress

I'd like to restrict sign ups as Subscribers to my Wordpress website to certain countries only.

I don't want to restrict website visitors though - just sign ups.

I've searched Google and the Wordpress plugin repository and can't find a free solution.

There is a solution from WPMU DEV, but this requires a paid membership to obtain and an ongoing membership to keep updated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [iQ Block Country](https://wordpress.org/plugins/iq-block-country/) plugin did the trick.

It allowed me to specify which countries are able to view the front end of my website.

The plugin is free.